# Get column names of all the fields of a join Query in MySql

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

This is my simple join query, first table has 5 different fields and second one has three different fields and the join query is providing me 8 fields:

```
SELECT * FROM admin_users au
INNER JOIN admin_user_data aud
WHERE au.id = aud.admin_id
```

I want a MYSQL query that returns me all the eight field names and also its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You are looking for this...

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    column_type    # or data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name in('admin_users' ,'admin_user_data');
```

Answer (score 0):

The data must be in same format.

Suppose

Here

table1

id   Sub
1   ,English
2   ,Hindi

table2

id sub
1  Hindi
2  Malayalam
2  Science
1  Maths

for join these two tables  use 'union'

select * from table1 union select * from table2