# How to get all the headers of a joined table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to get an array with all the headers of my joined table. For the joined table, the headers look like: Student.SID etc. I tried two different things; the code below did work before joining but now it gives me an error. I also tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599825/get-column-names-of-all-the-fields-of-a-join-query-in-mysql) solution. But this gives a different order of the headers than the order in my joined tables. I need the order to be the same.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM (STUDENT
LEFT JOIN CLASS ON STUDENT.SID = CLASS.SID)
```

Does someone know how to get the headers for a joined table in SQL?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the statement `all the headers of my joined table`

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: select 
 student.*,
 class.*
from
 STUDENT
 LEFT JOIN CLASS ON STUDENT.SID = CLASS.SID

Comment: Accepted solution in the link looks correct..Please add your table definitions and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean just the name of the column. Like in python pandas you can use data.columns which shows you all the headers of the table.